# how to color scrollbar in mozilla?

Tags: css

Am capable of chaging the color of scrollbar in webkit browser like chrome and safari.
But in order to color it in mozilla I dont have any stuffs. Can you tell me any ideas of how to color without javascript? Pls help me..

Comment: hey will you please give me the code by which you can change the color of scrollbarin chrome..?

Answer (score 0):

You can't style scrollbars in Gecko yet.

Comment: ...and please don't in webkit either. I like my styles the way they are. If you're implementing a customized interface for elements on the page, use javascript, and make it look nice.

Comment: Using native elements is usually better for accessibility than a bunch of divs and spans.

Comment: @zzzzBov i agree if you're trying to tweak the main page scrollbar, but i don't have a problem if you're changing an internal scrollbar, a la Trello. Sometimes you have limited space, and if you can clean up the interface by making some good tweaks to the scrollbar, i say go for it. other browsers will just ignore your CSS anyways. why not give an improved experience to webkit users?

Comment: @Jason, I've actually changed my mind in the (nearly) two years since I wrote that comment. I've seen enough use cases where styling scrollbars to fit the theme of the site provides a much cleaner experience than when the standard scrollbars are used. Gmail in particular makes good use of custom scrollbar styles. Additionally, as Lea said, there's *much* better accessibility support for the browser's built-in scrollbars than there is for custom JS scrollbars.